# Problem with this error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize' OpenCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I got stuck with this error after running resize function line:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3_custom.cfg', 'yolov3_custom_last.weights')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
   _, img = cap.read()
   img = cv2.resize(img,(1280,720))
   hight,width,_ = img.shape
   blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255,(416,416), (0,0,0), swapRB = True,crop= False)
```

Comment: Dear Maham, please clean up the question; they are plenty of 'enter code here'. thx

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of no frames is getting captured.

Please try

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

Comment: thanks to reply me! but this is not working in my case

Comment: please try changing index to -1, 1, 0, 2

Comment: which indexes should i change can u explain me?

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

Try changing index

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that there is no frame captured as such, there is no image available to be resized. In order to be sure that your webcam is actually capturing, try this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
   ret, img = cap.read()
   if not ret:
      print("no frame captured")
      exit()

   img = cv2.resize(img,(1280,720))
   #continue processing
```

Then
Test to be sure that your webcam is working properly OR
if you have multiple webcam, try using another index to init the "VideoCapture"

```
cap = VideoCapture(1)
```

Comment: appreciating for your answer but i still get this error i don't understand what is the reason behind it my webcam is working properly fine. kindly helping me if u could. i will be very thankful

Comment: when you ran the above, did you see this printed out to console, "no frame captured"?

Comment: Yes it is printing.. actually i ran on raspberry pi so may be this problem belong to picamera i don't know i am totally blank now i had been trying since a weak to solve this problem but nothing could happening.☹

Comment: then the problem is with the camera hardware itself, try and use another camera

Comment: when i run code for camera only then it is working fine, but within above code it not captures anything?